# Java Transferring Byte arrays over socket corrupted data

Tags: java, file, sockets, byte

I'm transferring Byte arrays of different kinds of files(.png, .txt, etc..) My socket starts sending the data and client starts receiving it. For some reason .pngs doesen't look same as they do on the server side. (Sometimes it says image is unreadable, sometimes only some parts of image are shown.. etc)? I'm wondering how could I make it so that the sent data would actually be the same as the sent data? Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong? (Note! If .png file has alpha channel, image seems always to be completely unreadable.)

Client side of the data transfer:

```
try
    {
        sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Input = socket.getInputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException eIO) {
        System.out.println("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + eIO);
        return false;
    }
.
.
.
LoadCache[] filedata = (LoadCache[]) sInput.readObject(); //This contains the path and size of file
                    while(number < filedata.length){
                        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) LoadCache.getSize(filedata[number])];
                        String result = Reader.UpdateCache(LoadCache.getPath(filedata[number]));
                        number++;
                        if(result != "skip" && result != "Stop"){
                            BufferedOutputStream Bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(result));
                            int BytesRead = Input.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                            Bos.write(mybytearray, 0, BytesRead);
                            Bos.close();
                        }
                    }
```

Server side of the data transfer:

```
Socket socket;
ObjectInputStream sInput;
ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
OutputStream Output;
BufferedInputStream buffIn;
.
.
.
try{
    sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    Output = socket.getOutputStream();
} catch (Exception e){
System.out.println("Couldn't create Input/Output streams");
}
.
.
.
File[] Data = Reader.getFiles(Action.getString(Incomingdata.getAction(datain)));
                    LoadCache LoadedCache[] = new LoadCache[Data.length];
                    for(int i = 0; i<Data.length; i++){
                        Path filePath = Paths.get(Data[i].getPath());
                        Path relativePath = base.relativize(filePath); //= filePath - base (so to say)
                        LoadedCache[i] = new LoadCache(relativePath.toString(), Data[i].length());
                    }
                    System.out.println(LoadedCache.length);
                    try {
                        sOutput.writeObject(LoadedCache);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    for(File file : Data){
                        try {
                            if(file.isFile()){
                                byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                                buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                                buffIn.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
                                Output.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
                                Output.flush();
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        buffIn.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Also! Now (I'm not quite sure anymore if I got this earlier) Client gives me `java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check` -Exception (And none of the files is zipped)

Something Runnable:

```
Public class Client {
private ObjectInputStream sInput;       // to read from the socket
private static ObjectOutputStream sOutput;      // to write on the socket
private static Socket socket;
public static Client client;
public static Player player;
public static boolean loadingFiles;

String server;
int port;
boolean connected;

Client(String server, int port) {
    this.server = server;
    this.port = port;
    this.connected = true;
}

public static boolean isConnected(Client client){
    return client.connected;
}

private void disconnect() {
    try { 
        if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
    try {
        if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
    try{
        if(socket != null) socket.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
}

public boolean start() {
    // try to connect to the server
    try {
        socket = new Socket(server, port);
    } 
    // if it failed we catch the exception
    catch(Exception ec) {
        System.out.println("Error connecting to server: " + ec);
        return false;
    }

    System.out.println("Connection accepted " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort());

    /* Creating Data Streams */
    try
    {
        sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException eIO) {
        System.out.println("Exception creating streams: " + eIO);
        return false;
    }
    // creates the Thread to listen from the server 
    new ListenFromServer().start();
    String Cache;
    if(Reader.ReadCache(Frame.drive +"//FM_Cache/version") == "WeHadToMakeNewFile"){ //If we don't have that file. We create it, but now it's empty.
        Cache = "New";
    }
    else{ //If we do have cache and it has "version" we send our version to server.
        Cache = Reader.ReadCache(Frame.drive +"FM_Cache/version");
    }
    send(new Incomingdata("", "", new Action(0, Cache, 0, 0)));

    // success we inform the caller that it worked
    return true;
}

public static void Connect() {
    // default values
    int portNumber = 16304;
    String serverAddress = "0.0.0.0"; //I'm using my own ip here..

    // create the Client object
    client = new Client(serverAddress, portNumber);
    // test if we can start the connection to the Server
    if(client.start()){
            client.connected = true;
            }
}

public static void Disconnect(Client client) {
    client.connected = false;
    client.disconnect();
}

class ListenFromServer extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        loadingFiles = true;
        while(true) {
            try {
                    int number = 0;
                    LoadCache[] filedata = (LoadCache[]) sInput.readObject();
                    while(number < filedata.length){
                        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) LoadCache.getSize(filedata[number])];
                        String result = Reader.UpdateCache(LoadCache.getPath(filedata[number]));
                        number++;
                        if(result != "skip" && result != "Stop"){
                            BufferedOutputStream Bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(result));
                            int BytesRead = sInput.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                            Bos.write(mybytearray, 0, BytesRead);
                            Bos.close();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Cache has been patched succesfully!");
                    Client.loadingFiles = false;
            }catch(EOFException e){
                System.out.println("Problem reading the data streams! " +e);
                break;
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                break;
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
            }
        } 
    } 
}

public static void send(Incomingdata incomingdata) {
    try {
        sOutput.writeObject(incomingdata);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception writing to server: " + e);
    }
}
}
```

Incomingdata:

```
package com.connection;

import com.connection.Action;

public class Incomingdata implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1309997274550304156L;
private String Username, Password;
private Action action;

public Incomingdata(String Username, String Password, Action action){
    this.Username = Username;
    this.action = action;
    this.Password = Password;
}

public static String getUsername(Incomingdata Incomingdata){
    return Incomingdata.Username;
}
public static String getPassword(Incomingdata Incomingdata){
    return Incomingdata.Password;
}
public static Action getAction(Incomingdata Incomingdata){
    return Incomingdata.action;
}
}
```

LoadingCache:

```
package com.connection;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class LoadCache implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7267682639705707967L;
String path;
long size;

public LoadCache(String path, long size){
    this.path = path;
    this.size = size;
}

public static long getSize(LoadCache cache) {
    return cache.size;
}

public static String getPath(LoadCache filedata) {
    return filedata.path;
}
}
```

Action.java:

```
package com.connection;

import com.connection.Action;

public class Action implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4389420849399916526L;
int type, x, y;
String string;

public Action(int type, String string, int x, int y){
    this.type = type;
    this.string = string;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public static int getType(Action action) {
    return action.type;
}

public static String getString(Action action) {
    return action.string;
}

public static int getX(Action action) {
    return action.x;
}

public static int getY(Action action) {
    return action.y;
}
}
```

And Reader for Client. This should be the last class you need to run the client.

```
package com.game.loader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.connection.Client;
import com.game.Frame;
import com.game.menu.GameMenu;

public class Reader {

public static String ReadCache(String string) {
    int CurrentLine = 0;
    String returnement = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(string)));
        for(String line = Reader.readLine(); line != null; line = Reader.readLine()){
            if(CurrentLine == 0){
                returnement = line;
            }
            CurrentLine++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        new File(Frame.drive +"//FM_Cache").mkdirs();
        return "WeHadToMakeNewFile";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnement;
}

public static String UpdateCache(String path) {
    String[] pieces = path.split("/");
    String returnement = "skip";
    System.out.println(Frame.drive + "//FM_Cache/" + path);
    if(new File(Frame.drive +"//FM_Cache/" +path).exists()){
        returnement = (Frame.drive +"//FM_Cache/" +path);
    }
    else{ //If file doesen't exit we make one and parent folders.
        File file = new File(Frame.drive +"//FM_Cache/" +path);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        returnement = (Frame.drive +"//FM_Cache/" +path);
    }
    return returnement;
}

}
```

Runnable server:

```
package com.server;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.connection.Action;
import com.connection.Incomingdata;
import com.connection.LoadCache;
import com.game.loader.Reader;
import com.game.player.Player;

public class Server {
//Every connection got their own unique id
private static int uniqueId;
//List all the clients
private static ArrayList<ClientThread> al;
private static boolean running = false;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
final Path base = Paths.get("Data", "Cache");

public Server(int port) {
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    al = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
}

public void start() {
    running = true;
    try {
        //Server socket
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Screen.portnumber);
        System.out.println("Server is running and waiting for Clients to connect.");
        while(running){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            if(!running){ //this will make server running stop.
                System.out.println("Closing the server..");
                break;
            }
            ClientThread t = new ClientThread(socket);
            al.add(t); //saving new client to our arraylist.
            t.run();
        }
        try{
            serverSocket.close();
            for(int i = 0; i< al.size(); i++){//We forget about all the clients.
                //Maybe also save all the data here?
                ClientThread tc = al.get(i);
                try{
                    tc.sInput.close();
                    tc.sOutput.close();
                    tc.socket.close();
                }
                catch(IOException ioE){}

            }
        } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void close() {
    running = false;
    try {
        new Socket("localhost", Screen.portnumber);
    } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Can't disconnect.."); }
}

    synchronized void remove(int id) {
        // scan the array list until we find the Id
        for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
            ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
            // found it
            if(ct.id == id) {
                al.remove(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

public static boolean isRunning(){
    return running;
}

    class ClientThread extends Thread {
        //The socket where to listen/talk
        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream sInput;
        ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
        BufferedInputStream buffIn;
        //my unique id (easier for deconnection)
        int id;
        //Objects that we will be receiving
        Incomingdata datain;
        //the date we connect
        String date;
        Player player;
        boolean Connected = false;

        //Constructor
        ClientThread(Socket socket){
            id = uniqueId++;
            this.socket = socket;
            try{
                sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Couldn't create Input/Output streams");
            }
            date = new Date().toString();
        }

        // what will run forever
        public void run() {
            // to loop until LOGOUT
            Connected = true;
            while(Connected) {
                try {
                    datain = (Incomingdata) sInput.readObject();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception reading Streams: " + e);
                    break;              
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                    break;
                }
                if(!Incomingdata.getUsername(datain).isEmpty()){
                    switch(Action.getType(Incomingdata.getAction(datain))) { //CHANGE!!

                    case 0://Log in/off
                        System.out.println(Incomingdata.getUsername(datain) +", " +Incomingdata.getPassword(datain) + " trying to connect.");
                        if(Player.getPassword(Reader.ReadPlayerData("Data/Players/" +Incomingdata.getUsername(datain) +".txt")) == Incomingdata.getPassword(datain)){
                            player = Reader.ReadPlayerData("Data/Players/" +Incomingdata.getUsername(datain) +".txt");
                            System.out.println(Player.getUsername(player) +"Just connected!");
                            Player.isOnline(player);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1://Talk
                        System.out.println(Incomingdata.getUsername(datain) + ": " +Action.getString(Incomingdata.getAction(datain)));
                        break;
                    case 2://Move

                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if(Action.getString(Incomingdata.getAction(datain)) != null){
                    File[] Data = Reader.getFiles(Action.getString(Incomingdata.getAction(datain)));
                    LoadCache LoadedCache[] = new LoadCache[Data.length];
                    for(int i = 0; i<Data.length; i++){
                        Path filePath = Paths.get(Data[i].getPath());
                        Path relativePath = base.relativize(filePath); //= filePath - base (so to say)
                        LoadedCache[i] = new LoadCache(relativePath.toString(), Data[i].length());
                    }
                    System.out.println(LoadedCache.length);
                    try {
                        sOutput.writeObject(LoadedCache);
                        sOutput.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    for(File file : Data){
                        try {
                            if(file.isFile()){
                                byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                                buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                                buffIn.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
                                sOutput.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
                                sOutput.flush();
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        buffIn.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Cache updated!");
                }
            }
            // remove myself from the arrayList containing the list of the
            System.out.println(Player.getUsername(player) +", " +Player.getPassword(player) +" disconnected.");
            remove(id);
            close();
        }

        // try to close everything
        private void close() {
            // try to close the connection
            try {
                if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {}
            try {
                if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {};
            try {
                if(socket != null) socket.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Reader.java for server:

```
package com.game.loader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.FileFileFilter;

import com.game.player.CharacterClass;
import com.game.player.Equipment;
import com.game.player.Friends;
import com.game.player.Inventory;
import com.game.player.Orbs;
import com.game.player.Player;
import com.game.player.Quest;
import com.game.world.Tile;

public class Reader {

public static Player temporary;
static int stage = 0;
private static int count = 0;
private static int totalfolders = 0;
private static File[] files = new File[NumberOfFiles("Data/Cache/")];

public static Player ReadPlayerData(String string) {
    Player player = null;
    int CurrentLine = 0;
    String[] All = new String[100]; //This may need to be extended.
    try {
        BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(string)));
        for(String line = Reader.readLine(); line != null; line = Reader.readLine()){
            All[CurrentLine] = line;
            CurrentLine++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Someone is trying to log in using wrong username.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player = new Player(string, All[0], new Tile(Integer.parseInt(All[1].split(", ")[0]), Integer.parseInt(All[1].split(", ")[1]), Integer.parseInt(All[1].split(", ")[2])),
    Integer.parseInt(All[2]), Integer.parseInt(All[3]), Integer.parseInt(All[4]), new CharacterClass(All[5]), new Orbs(All[6].split(", ")), null, new Inventory(All[8].split(", ")),
    null, new Equipment(All[10].split(", ")), new Friends(All[11].split(", ")), /* All[12] = guild,*/ Integer.parseInt(All[13]), true, false, null, null, Integer.parseInt(All[18]), /*All[19] = StartDate,*/ All[20]);
    temporary = player;
    return player;
}

public static boolean CacheReader(String string) {
    File[] all = new File(string).listFiles(); //We list all the files from path
    int folders = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < all.length; i++){
        if(!all[i].isDirectory()) { //folders are not added to this list. :)
            System.out.println("((i = " +i +") - (folders = " +folders +")) + (stage = " +stage +") = " +(i-folders+stage));
            files[i-folders+stage] = all[i];
        }
        else{
            folders++;
            totalfolders++;
        }
    }
    stage += all.length-folders; //We add number of files from every directory to stage.
    for(int i = 0; i < all.length; i++){ //Then we seek for all the sub-directories
        if(all[i].isDirectory()){
            CacheReader(all[i].getPath()); //and add all the files from sub-directories to out file list
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static File[] getFiles(String string) {
    if(string == "New"){
    }
    return files;
}

public static int NumberOfFiles(String string) {
    File[] filenames;
    filenames = new File(string).listFiles();
    count += filenames.length; //We add all the files from the File(string) Note!: Also folders
    for(int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++){
        if(filenames[i].isDirectory()){
            NumberOfFiles(filenames[i].getPath());
            count--;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Umm.. I think you can remove everything related to player, since it's not part of cache update system.. also there are some unused imports in those, I didn't remove all of them. Most of TextArea.Addline();s I changed to System.out.println(); if you find one, you can aswell replace it with System.out.println(); or if you don't need it you can remove it. What ever.. I just would like to find an answer..

Comment: Have you tried flushing your `sOutput` (object stream) after writing?

Comment: I'd also suggest generating a checksum on each side and comparing them.

Comment: In the client side you are mixing reads from the ObjectOutputStream and the underlying OutputStream. It seems a bit weird, because one is a wrapper of the other. The same in the server side.

Comment: @rafalopez79 Okay, thanks for that :D I made it so that I only use ObjectStreams for everything, but it didn't fix the problem though..

Comment: @spudone check sum the number of files or number of bytes in every file or what?

Comment: @user3738243 please, post some runnable code, to try to debug it.

Comment: @rafalopez79 There's some runnable :D I'm not quite sure if it will run with that (you might need to remove some unused imports and stuff.. )

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use multiple streams to read from the same socket, or write to it either. Use the object streams for everything.
2. Your copy loops are incorrect, because they aren't loops. You can't assume that `read()` fills the buffer. The canonical stream copy loop in Java is like so:

   ```
   int count;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more, code works with any size >= 1
   while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
   {
       out.write(buffer, 0, count);
   }
   ```

Comment: Great advice but that didn't solve the problem. :) But Thanks for advice

Comment: What do you think of Creating Serverside Byte array using:

    `byte[] bytearray = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());`

Comment: @user3738243 What I think is that you shouldn't read entire files into memory. It wastes both time and space.

Answer (score 0):

try to write the byte array to the ObjectOutputStream as an object:

```
 final byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
 buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
 buffIn.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
 sOutput.writeObject(bytearray);
```

And to read it as an Object:

```
 final BufferedOutputStream Bos = 
    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(result));
 byte[] mybytearray = (byte[])sInput.readObject();
 Bos.write(mybytearray, 0, BytesRead);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: But on server.java I have: "sOutput.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);" Does it differ from "sOutput.writeObject(bytearray)"? and what's the difference? Sure I can try this out, but explanation would be also nice :)

Comment: @user3738243 I think it´s easier to see what´s happening and easier to debug it. The byte array object you send has the same content in both sides of the wire.